# does using $.ajax slows down the website? what's the best way to retrieve instant data from a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im using alot of $.ajax calls in my website that im working on and it seems to be slow and lagging at some points. Is there any faster way to retrieve data other than using the $.ajax ?

```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: path + 'helper/general/general.php',
     data: {pass:pass},
     success: function(data){
        if(data == 'correct'){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: path + 'helper/process/ClassesProcess.php',
                data: {classID: classID}
            });
        }else{
            $('.feedback').html(wrong_password).slideDown();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to change your architecture to reduce the number of the requests in general and do some profiling to find the bottlenecks of your code(and to make sure that it is continuous ajax queries are slowing down the site).

Comment: im using as less as possible of requests but its still lagging sometimes. is it because of these requests or could it be something else ?

Comment: There might be some faster way to load content after page load, but the difference will be marginal. The real "slowdown" you get when using ajax (or any other after-pageload-requests) is the fact that you have to wait once more for the roundtrip client->server->client, and even if you sit close to your server with a high speed internet connection you will probably never get your content faster then 40ms after you send your request. 40ms is not much, but chain these together and you will start noticing slowdowns. (eg: 13 such calls in a sequence > half a second)

Comment: Define what you mean with lag (for example, in today's gaming-community lag usually have nothing to do with network latency...)

Comment: yes there's a noticed time like 1 sec to retrieve a big amount of data, so what other ways can i use ? im fine by changing them but i dont want it to be slo

Comment: the whole website just jams for couple seconds and makes the computer stop as well, it doesnt always happen to my computer but it does to all my friends tht are testing the website @Snellface

Comment: That doesn't sound like an issue with the server.  Although finding the heaviest use of the server's processes is important.  This to me sounds like your friend's browsers are struggling to process a large amount of response data.

Comment: so you're saying that coding this way is safe ?

Comment: It depends.  How many requests per browser per second are be talking, and now large are the requests/responses?

Comment: only when posting new things in a form like posting, fetching the data to view it in a table. that kind of requests.
its not happening like in an interval

Comment: If anything then, that is actually more efficient.  Since it doesn't have the overhead of including and entire HTML document with each request.

Comment: `instant data` can't be done with simple _ajax_ or form submit or page request in general. You're probably asking for [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Comment: I use an ajax request on a site i'm working on because we have a database query that sometimes take quite a while to perform. I have opted to load the main page data/layout first, and request this "heavy" data that take some time once the rest of the page have been loaded. This makes the whole process takes a bit longer then if i did it in one go, but the overall experience is still better the way it is now. However when the request is made and the browser waits for the response / processes it there is no noticeable slowdowns (i mostly run chrome though, and chromes javascript engine is great)

Answer (score 1):

Ways in which I think you could optimise this are:

1. Use === instead of == in an if statement, this way it will check the type before the value.
2. Instead of doing an ajax call with in an ajax call, surely your first call should do all the logic (try to avoid having logic in your front-end)
3. Instead of returning strings or html from your ajax calls, return JSON if you can... however be wary of using json_encode/json_decode in php as they seem to be two slow functions.
4. If the user is refreshing the page, they don't need to redownload the content for a lot of your ajax calls, if the data hasen't changed since that user's last request, return a 304 with no data instead of returning a 200 with the data. This will make the browser get the previous response from it's cache.
5. Avoid declaring a function where there should be a callback, instead, put the name of a pre-existing function, this will stop the function being reinitialised every time you execute you ajax method.
6. Finally, when using jQuery, try to target elements by id instead of class, jQuery finds the element a lot faster this way as ids should be unique in a webpage.